# Regex Not Greedy Behavior

Tags: regex

I am just fooling around with regex queries and have a question.

Pattern:

```
param(.*?(\d*))(.*?),
```

String:

```
"param":123432412341,
```

Why is the 3rd group catching the entirety of the string after the explicit text match? it seems like `\d*` is behaving in a lazy manner in this scenario, with the first `.*?` matching nothing and `\d*` matching nothing.

Comment: As a side note, I never use nested capturing groups. If I need to (for alternation, i.e. `foo(ba(?:r|z))`), I use a non-capturing group.

Comment: In a question like this, it would be helpful to identify what you expect, like "I expected the second group to capture all the digits").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get the expected result by changing [`\d*` to `\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/kV9uZ9/1). This is because a lazy match (`.*?`) will stop as soon as the next piece of the expression is matched. This lazy match starts at the `"` after param and checks to see if `\d*` matches (it does -- there are 0+ digits at that position) and then continues and matches `(.*?),`. When you switch it to `\d+` the `"` is no longer matched and the first lazy dot-match-all continues to eat up characters until the first digit (like expected).

Another way to fix it would be [removing the second `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/kV9uZ9/2) altogether (it probably isn't needed anyways because an integer won't have any non-digit characters between it and the comma). This works because after `\d*` matches the `"` (as previously explained), the comma will fail to match and the lazy dot-match-all will continue to match characters until there are 0+ digits followed by a comma.

Also note, that sometimes (if your expression can be specific enough) a lazy dot-match-all isn't as efficient as using a negated character class. Another way to write this would be by using [`\D*` (`[^\d]`) instead of `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/kV9uZ9/3). This matches in 12 steps instead of 45 (original regex), 21 (using `\d+`), and 24 (removing second `.*?`).

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear, but this is exactly what I was asking about. Thanks for the clear explanation.